# maximizing cardinality of set with minimum distance lower bound

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, set-theory, uniform-distribution, coding-theory

Im looking to understand how to bound the following. Let $S\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ be an arbitrary subset of the Boolean cube. What is the largest $|S|$ such that for every $x,y\in S$, we have that $d(x,y)\geq n\cdot \delta$ (for arbitrary ranges of $\alpha$), where $d(x,y)=\sum_i [x_i\neq y_i]$.

Plotkin bound seems to give something for $S$ which is a *linear*  code (also it applies only for restricted ranges of distance, not generically for all $\delta$), but apart from that, i dont see what else bounds we have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is the general coding theory problem and doesn't have a closed form solution, though some bounds do exist.

By the way your arbitrary subset $S$ is a *code*, though not necessarily linear. So the Plotkin bound applies.

A subset $S$ which is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ is a binary linear code. The best upper bound will depend on $\alpha$ and also whether you are interested in asymptotics.

There is a nice short chapter describing what is known [here](https://algo.epfl.ch/_media/en/courses/2008-2009/mct_l03.pdf). The quantity $\alpha_2(x)$ is what you are interested in. In general unless $\alpha$ is very small the best upper bound is the so-called MRRW (4 Americans) bound of McEliece-Rumsey-Rudemich-Welch obtained by linear programming. Here is a plot from that Chapter, the lower bound there is Gilbert-Varshamov, and all the others are upper bounds.

[image]

At low rates, Hamming is the best. The bound is on the exponent therefore it is
$$
|S|\leq 2^{\alpha_2(\delta)\cdot n},
$$
as you point out.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Looking at the pdf you referenced, I suppose the upper bound on $|S|\leq \alpha_2(\delta)\cdot n$ or should it be $|S|\leq 2^{\alpha_2(\delta)\cdot n}$?

Comment: Could i ask another question here: the following confuses me a little bit. Think of $\delta=1/2$, in that case we are looking for a set of codewords of length $n$ and distance $1/2$, and the upper bound we get from the above is $2^{\alpha_2(1/2)n}$ but we know that the Hadamard code has only $n$ codewords, so is there any better upper bound?